# Что происходит с объектом при удалении ссылки на него?

Tags: java, объекты, переменные, ссылки, null

Есть три строки кода:

```
   String s = null; 
    s = "Hellow";
    s = null;
```

1. Создали переменную `s` типа `String`, которая ни на что не ссылается (хранит пустую ссылку `null`).
2. Создаем объект-строку `Hellow`, переменная `s` хранит ссылку на объект.
3. Удаляем из переменной `s` ссылку на объект.

---

**Вопрос**: что происходит со строкой `Hellow` после удаления ссылки на неё? Остаётся ли она в памяти или удаляется вместе со ссылкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java за удаление неиспользуемых объектов отвечает *сборщик мусора* (анг. *garbage collector*). Он автоматически вызывается JVM в определённые моменты времени и удаляет те объекты, которые в данный момент в приложении не используются.

Однако в примере, приведённом вами, сборщик мусора не удалит строку, хоть вы и удалили ссылку на неё и более не используете. Дело в том, что строки в Java, создаваемые посредством кавычек, а не конструкторов, помещаются в так называемый *пул строк* (анг. *string pool*), который сборщиком мусора не затрагивается. Когда вы делаете так

```
s = "Hellow";
```

вы создаёте строку, которая будет помещена в пул строк. И даже если после этого `s` перестанет указывать на неё

```
s = null;
```

строка "Hellow" никогда не будет собрана сборщиком мусора, она останется в памяти, то есть, в пуле строк. Поэтому если далее сделать так

```
String s2 = "Hellow";
System.out.println("Hellow" == s2);
```

на экран будет выведено `true`. Потому что мы не создали новую строку, а указали на имеющуюся в пуле строк.

Однако если создавать строки посредством конструкторов

```
String s = new String("Hellow");
```

а затем затирать ссылки на них

```
s = null;
```

то в таком случае строки будут удаляться сборщиком мусора, как и любые обыкновенные объекты. И, например, такой код

```
String s2 = new String("Hellow");
System.out.println(new String("Hellow") == s2);
```

выведет на экран `false`, так как в обоих случаях создаются две независимые друг от друга строки "Hellow", находящиеся в разных местах памяти и при этом не находящиеся в пуле строк. Такие строки при затирании ссылок на них будут удаляться сборщиком мусора.

Answer (score 3):

В данном сценарии строковый литерал `"Hellow"` определён в момент компиляции и соответственно будет размещён в пуле строк (string pool).

В старых версиях (Java 6 и раньше) пул строк являлся частью постоянной области памяти PermGen, которая не относилась к основной куче (Heap) и имела постоянный размер, который нельзя было увеличить.
Сборка мусора запускается только при условии, что существующая память исчерпана.  Как правило, вероятность такого сценария для постоянной области памяти пренебрежимо мала -- нужно было бы или загружать множество классов или постоянно добавлять в пул новые строки при помощи `String::intern`.  В худшем случае можно было бы добиться и `OutOfMemoryError`.

Начиная с Java 7 и выше пул строк размещается в куче (heap), для которой сборка мусора вызывается чаще (по сравнению с PermGen), при этом неиспользуемые строки удаляются из пула, освобождая память.
При необходимости размер кучи может увеличиваться, в том числе и превышая объём доступной физической памяти.

> *что происходит со строкой "Hellow" после удаления ссылки на неё? Остаётся ли она в памяти или удаляется вместе со ссылкой?*

Строка останется в памяти (в данном случае, в пуле строк) до тех пор, пока не будет вызван сборщик мусора или не завершится программа.

Answer (score 0):

Все вспоминают про то, что в java учетом используемых ссылок и подчисткой неиспользованной памяти занимается не программист, а сборщик мусора, но забывают, что и выделением памяти тоже занимается не программист. В приведенном фрагменте оптимизирующий компилятор сразу распознает паттерн присваивания без использования результата и не будет создавать строку и выполнять присваивание, так как результат от этого не изменится.

Answer (score -3):

Она удалиться сборщиком мусора